# How to manage saving custom field from Quick edit and Post Save using save_post action hook without colliding each other?

Tags: save-post, bulk, quick-edit

I's following Rachel Carden's [tutorial on creating Quick Edit and Bulk Edit](http://wpdreamer.com/2012/03/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/), and grabbed her full work from her [github repo](https://github.com/bamadesigner/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit). I managed doing everything fine and I made a checkbox instead of radio buttons for one of my field called "Featured" (meta_key: `pre_featured`).

I made some changes to the concept though? As I's using a checkbox instead of [Radio Buttons](https://github.com/bamadesigner/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/blob/master/manage_wordpress_posts_using_bulk_edit_and_quick_edit.php#L350-L355) I had only one state: **"checked ? grab the value 'yes' : else null"**. So I made the [update_meta part](https://github.com/bamadesigner/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/blob/master/manage_wordpress_posts_using_bulk_edit_and_quick_edit.php#L468-L469) differently:

```
foreach( $custom_fields as $q_field ) {            
    if ( array_key_exists( $q_field, $_POST ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $project_prefix . $q_field, $_POST[ $q_field ] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $project_prefix . $q_field ); //delete if not checked
    }
}
```

It's working awesomely good.

But now when I's implementing the meta field update in New Post page or Update Post Page, something odd happened. I'm using [Tammy Hart Reusable Custom Meta Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259) for saving meta fields value while saving in `post.php` or `post-new.php`. And **found**, in both the cases the custom fields are saving using `'save_post'` action hook.

Whenever I'm saving my Post, two meta fields with same name getting override, like-
Post page is taking `pre_featured` a value: `yes`, and saving it, and again, the `else` part of that quick edit function is deleting it again.

I can't understand why it's happening, both the function have individual nonce checker and should work individually. But they are colliding. :(

**Post Save function:**

```
function save_cpt_specifics_meta( $post_id ) {
    $project_prefix = 'pre_';
    $cpt_specifics_fields = get_cpt_specifics( $post_id, $project_prefix ); //taking my fields that's working for other fields undoubtedly

    // verify nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['cpt_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['cpt_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    // check autosave
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;
    // check permissions
    if ( 'offers' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id) )
            return $post_id;
        } elseif ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) {
            return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ( $cpt_specifics_fields as $field ) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ( $new && $new != $old ) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ( '' == $new && $old ) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } // end foreach
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_cpt_specifics_meta', 10);
add_action('new_to_publish', 'save_cpt_specifics_meta', 10);
```

**Quick Edit Save function:**

```
function project_save_quick_edit_featured_data( $post_id, $post ) {
    $project_prefix = 'pre_';

    // pointless if $_POST is empty (this happens on bulk edit)
    if ( empty( $_POST ) )
        return $post_id;

    // verify quick edit nonce
    if ( isset( $_POST[ '_inline_edit' ] ) && ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ '_inline_edit' ], 'inlineeditnonce' ) )
        return $post_id;

    // don't save for autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // dont save for revisions
    if ( isset( $post->post_type ) && $post->post_type == 'revision' )
        return $post_id;

    switch( $post->post_type ) {    
        case 'cpt':        
            /**
             * Because this action is run in several places, checking for the array key
             * keeps WordPress from editing data that wasn't in the form, i.e. if you had
             * this post meta on your "Quick Edit" but didn't have it on the "Edit Post" screen.
             */
            $custom_fields = array( 'featured' );

            foreach( $custom_fields as $q_field ) {            
                if ( array_key_exists( $q_field, $_POST ) ) {
                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $project_prefix . $q_field, $_POST[ $q_field ] );
                } else {
                    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $project_prefix . $q_field ); //delete if not checked
                }
            }
            break;            
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'project_save_quick_edit_featured_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Why are you using g two fields with the same name?

Comment: Why not? Because they are sharing the same property - whether the post is featured or not. Na?